# How to prevent cURL errors: Warning: curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php, curl

Hello I have a script the uses cURL, It can be executed in many different hosts I don't know it's configuration. I have a check script, but I still get cURL errors in some hosts.

My script

```
if (!in_array('curl', get_loaded_extensions())) {
    // bad configuration message goes here, exit the app
}
```

Error I get in some hosts:

> Warning:  curl_exec() has been disabled for security reasons

My question is how should I code my script to fully check cURL availability in the server

Thks

Comment: With `function_exists('curl_init')`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`function_exists`](http://php.net/function_exists). It also reports `false` for disabled functions.

That's not explicitly documented, but source code describes it well: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#1384.

Answer (score 2):

Write something like this..

```
echo function_exists('curl_version')?"You have it ;)":"You don't have cURL!!";
```

and I get an output on my screen as ..

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
You have it ;)
```